# Unable to resolve Static method?

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm new to android and heard about *retrofit*. But when I tried to implement this, I'm getting this error:

```
11-07 10:57:59.969    8036-8291/com.example.first.servicefirst W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in     signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
11-07 10:57:59.969    8036-8291/com.example.first.servicefirst W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in    signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
11-07 10:57:59.969    8036-8291/com.example.first.servicefirst I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method        java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.source
11-07 10:57:59.969    8036-8291/com.example.first.servicefirst W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 18524: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newInputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/InputStream;
```

I'm really confused where did I go wrong.

This is my main activity:

```
package com.example.first.servicefirst;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

 import com.squareup.okhttp.Interceptor;
 import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
 import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;

 import java.io.IOException;

 import retrofit.Call;
 import retrofit.Callback;
 import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
 import retrofit.Response;
 import retrofit.Retrofit;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public EditText password,userName;
Button login,resister;
ProgressBar progressbar;
TextView tv;
String TAG="Fails";
String url="http://172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/SF_UserLogin.svc";
private ModelLogin Result;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    userName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmployeeCode);

    login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignin);
    userName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorfoucs);

    //progess_msz.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ConnectivityManager cn=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nf=cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(nf != null && nf.isConnected()==true )
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
      showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,"No Network","Please Check Your Network Connectivity",true);
    }

    final   ConnectionDetector    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String s1 = userName.getText().toString();
            String s2 = password.getText().toString();
            if (s1.equals("")) {
                userName.setError("Enter User Name");
            }
            if (s2.equals("")) {
                password.setError("Enter Password");

            }
            try{
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();

                    // Customize the request
                    Request request = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("Accept", "application/json")
                            .header("Authorization", "auth-token")
                            .method(original.method(), original.body())
                            .build();

                    com.squareup.okhttp.Response response = chain.proceed(request);

                    // Customize or return the response
                    return response;
                }
            });
            Retrofit retro = new    Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
            RetrofitRest retrofitRest = retro.create(RetrofitRest.class);
            Call<ModelLogin>call=retrofitRest.getResult(s1, s2);

           //     Call<ModelLogin> callget=retrofitRest.verify(result);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelLogin>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response<ModelLogin> response, Retrofit retrofit)
                    {
                       ModelLogin modelLogin=new ModelLogin();
                       modelLogin.getLoginResult();
                        if(modelLogin.equals(2))
                        {
                            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fails",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
          //  call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelLogin>() {
           //     @Override
           //     public void onResponse(Response<ModelLogin> response, Retrofit retrofit) {


            //        }


            //    @Override
            //    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
             //       Log.d(TAG,"Error");
             //   }
            //});


        }catch (Exception e){
            throw e;
            }

        }
    });


}

    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    // Setting alert dialog icon


    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
 }
```

This is my interface:

```
package com.example.first.servicefirst;

import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.http.POST;
import retrofit.http.Path;


public interface RetrofitRest {

@POST("SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/login/{EMPLOYEECODE}/{PASSWORD}")
public  Call<ModelLogin>getResult(@Path("EMPLOYEECODE")String empcode,@Path("PASSWORD")String passwrd);

 }
```

My json response will be like this:

```
{"loginResult":"{\"Result\":2,\"UserID\":0,\"ModuleID\":1,\"ModuleName\":\"CRM\"}"}
```

This is my logcat:

```
    11-09 11:17:34.670  18964-18964/com.example.first.servicefirst D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
    11-09 11:17:34.770  18964-18964/com.example.first.servicefirst I/libthemeutils﹕ Theme： libthemeutil.so load     success
    11-09 11:17:34.830  18964-18964/com.example.first.servicefirst D/dalvikvm﹕ GetMethodID: not returning s    tatic         method Landroid/os/Process;.getTotalMemory ()J
    11-09 11:17:34.830  18964-18964/com.example.first.servicefirst D/dalvikvm﹕ GetMethodID: not returning static    method Landroid/os/Process;.getFreeMemory ()J
    11-09 11:17:34.980  18964-18964/com.example.first.servicefirst W/Toast﹕ From com.example.first.servicefirst, go ahead.
    11-09 11:17:35.070  18964-18964/com.example.first.servicefirst I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.2_RB1.04.04.04.154.004_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.2_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.15
    Build Date: 08/06/14 Wed
    Local Branch: mybranch4057433
    Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.2_rb1
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2.2_RB1.04.04.04.154.004 +  NOTHING
    11-09 11:17:35.240  18964-18964/com.example.first.servicefirst D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
     11-09 11:17:35.410  18964-18964/com.example.first.servicefirst I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id:    android.os.BinderProxy@424badd8 time:61392269
    11-09 11:17:41.420  18964-19350/com.example.first.servicefirst W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
    11-09 11:17:41.420  18964-19350/com.example.first.servicefirst W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
    11-09 11:17:41.420  18964-19350/com.example.first.servicefirst I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.sink
    11-09 11:17:41.420  18964-19350/com.example.first.servicefirst W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 18520: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newOutputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/OutputStream;
    11-09 11:17:41.420  18964-19350/com.example.first.servicefirst D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
    11-09 11:17:41.420  18964-19350/com.example.first.servicefirst W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
   11-09 11:17:41.420  18964-19350/com.example.first.servicefirst W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
    11-09 11:17:41.420  18964-19350/com.example.first.servicefirst I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.source
   11-09 11:17:41.420  18964-19350/com.example.first.servicefirst W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 18519: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newInputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/InputStream;
   11-09 11:17:41.420  18964-19350/com.example.first.servicefirst D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your parsing of response is not correct. Check with this code

```
     call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelLogin>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<ModelLogin> response, Retrofit retrofit)
                {

                    if(response.getLoginResult().getResult().equals("2")
                    {
                        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }
```

Comment: not working unable to resolve symbol getLoginResult()