# How to parse a json using retrofit 2.0?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Am having a doubt on parsing json objects using retrofit 
  my json response will be like this:

> {"loginResult":"{\"Result\":2,\"UserID\":0,\"ModuleID\":1,\"ModuleName\":\"CRM\"}"}

My doubt is if result from response is 2 it should redirect to next page . How to create pojo for this json response ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply,use `GsonConverterFactory`, before use that you need add this to your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson'
```

Let's say you have a Object called `LoginResponse` and it has a attribute called `loginResult`:

```
public class LoginResponse{
    LoginResult loginResult;
}
```

The `LoginResult` object define is like this:

```
public class LoginResult{
    int result;
    long userId;
    ...
}
```

Then use `Retrofit` to request:

```
    public interface APIService {
        @POST("SOMETHING/login")
        Call<LoginResponse> doLogin();

    }

    public void doSomething() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("YOUR LOGIN BASE URL")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        Call<LoginResponse> loginCall = service.doLogin();
        //if you want to request synchronous:
        LoginResponse response = loginCall.execute();
        //if you want to request asynchronous:
        LoginResponse response = loginCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
          @Override void onResponse(/* ... */) {
               // ...
           }

          @Override void onFailure(Throwable t) {
             // ...
          }
        });
    }
```

When you get the `LoginResponse`, you can do you work:

```
if(response.loginResult.result == 2){
    //do work here.something like startActivity(...);
}
```

Reference:

1. https://realm.io/news/droidcon-jake-wharton-simple-http-retrofit-2/
2. http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

Comment: do i need to create two pojo's

Comment: yes.Gson will automatic create the objects for you.

Comment: how to call like if result is 2 it will redirect to next activity in the main asynchronous retrofit

Comment: If you don't want to create POJOs, you can set the response type to JSONObject, and process it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579523/unable-to-resolve-static-method/33603183#33603183 this is my code

Answer (score 1):

Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create pojo class easily for your needs. In that set source type as json and Annotation style Gson. Adding yourjson as pojo created from there

```
     -----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

@SerializedName("loginResult")
@Expose
private LoginResult loginResult;

/**
* 
* @return
* The loginResult
*/
public LoginResult getLoginResult() {
return loginResult;
}

/**
* 
* @param loginResult
* The loginResult
*/
public void setLoginResult(LoginResult loginResult) {
this.loginResult = loginResult;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.LoginResult.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class LoginResult {

@SerializedName("Result")
@Expose
private Integer Result;
@SerializedName("UserID")
@Expose
private Integer UserID;
@SerializedName("ModuleID")
@Expose
private Integer ModuleID;
@SerializedName("ModuleName")
@Expose
private String ModuleName;

/**
* 
* @return
* The Result
*/
public Integer getResult() {
return Result;
}

/**
* 
* @param Result
* The Result
*/
public void setResult(Integer Result) {
this.Result = Result;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The UserID
*/
public Integer getUserID() {
return UserID;
}

/**
* 
* @param UserID
* The UserID
*/
public void setUserID(Integer UserID) {
this.UserID = UserID;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The ModuleID
*/
public Integer getModuleID() {
return ModuleID;
}

/**
* 
* @param ModuleID
* The ModuleID
*/
public void setModuleID(Integer ModuleID) {
this.ModuleID = ModuleID;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The ModuleName
*/
public String getModuleName() {
return ModuleName;
}

/**
* 
* @param ModuleName
* The ModuleName
*/
public void setModuleName(String ModuleName) {
this.ModuleName = ModuleName;
}

}
```

Comment: do i need to create two pojo

Comment: how to call like if result is 2 it will redirect to next activity in the main asynchronous retrofit

Comment: You need to implement to callback for that.. after successful request the callback's success method will execute.. In that callback you can redirect in to new activity

Comment: check above code.. In that logincall.enque method will execute

Comment: do i need to create object for Login result then do i need call getresult method or is there any other procedure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579523/unable-to-resolve-static-method/33603183#33603183 this is my code

Comment: are you getting any response from the server.. Please debug using studio ..then you can easily find out where is error happening..but in that question's log  its not appearing to be a network related issue..

Comment: i have resolved that issue now my prob is need to check with result which is coming as json response if it is 2 need to redirect to next activity need to post the user entered value from edittext

Comment: Added the answer for that question check it

Comment: need to get and validate result alone

Comment: if you use this pojo you can get the result by using loginresultobject.getLoginResult().getResult()